# Linq to XML GroupBy then OrderBy

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm somewhat stuck and can't think straight, maybe you're able to help me.

My .xml looks like this:

```
<RSA>
  <Size>
    <Name>0005-24</Name>
    <IDs>
      <ID>0003</ID>
      <ID>0004</ID>
      <ID>0005</ID>
      <ID>0006</ID>
      <ID>0007</ID>
      <ID>0008</ID>
      <ID>0010</ID>
      <ID>0009</ID>
    </IDs>
  </Size>
  <Size>
    <Name>0015-24</Name>
    <IDs>
      <ID>0003</ID>
      <ID>0004</ID>
      <ID>0005</ID>
      <ID>0006</ID>
      <ID>0007</ID>
      <ID>0008</ID>
      <ID>0010</ID>
      <ID>0009</ID>
    </IDs>
  </Size>
  <Size>
    <Name>003-12</Name>
    <IDs>
      <ID>0003</ID>
      <ID>0004</ID>
      <ID>0005</ID>
      <ID>0006</ID>
      <ID>0007</ID>
      <ID>0008</ID>
      <ID>0010</ID>
      <ID>0009</ID>
    </IDs>
  </Size>
</RSA>
```

And the IDs should be in order for readability.

**Edit:**

```
<Size>
  <Name>0005-24</Name>
    <IDs>
      <ID>0003</ID>
      <ID>0004</ID>
      <ID>0005</ID>
      <ID>0006</ID>
      <ID>0007</ID>
      <ID>0008</ID>
      <ID>0010</ID>   <-----
      <ID>0009</ID>   <-----
   </IDs>
</Size>
```

So these should be in order.

```
[...]
<ID>0009</ID>   <-----
<ID>0010</ID>   <-----
[...]
```

I tried many different approaches, but my last one ended with the following code, which doesn't work either.

```
 XElement root = XElement.Load(filePath + fileName);
 var compIDs = root.Elements()
               .GroupBy(r => r.Element("Name").Value)
               .OrderBy(xn => xn.Elements("RSA").Elements("Size").Elements("IDs").Elements("ID").ToString())
               .ToArray();
 root.ReplaceAll(compIDs);
 root.Save(filePath + fileName);
```

I searched SO in advance but couldn't find anything helpful, or it's just me who doesn't understand. ;)

Question: How do I group the entries by their Size, bring the IDs in order and replace them in the xml file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to group by size? they are already grouped by size in the XML. What is the expected output?

Comment: Can you elaborate on not working? Does it give an error? If not, what is the output?

Comment: Also what is the expected output? e.g. anonymous type projection or some sort of a new `XElement`.

Comment: @Moemoe, is the output an Xml document? Or an in-memory structure?

Comment: Do you want to just sort `<ID>` tags in each `<IDs>` tag?

Comment: The output is an xml document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var filename = ...

XDocument root = XDocument.Load(filename);

foreach (var ids_element in root.Descendants("IDs"))
{
    ids_element.ReplaceNodes(ids_element.Elements().OrderBy(x => x.Value));
}

root.Save(filename);
```

This code changes the `XDocument` in place. It loops through all elements of name "IDs", and it replaces the child elements with a sorted version of such child elements.

Comment: Obviously I was running in the wrong direction and overcomplicating things!  Thank you very much!

Comment: Yacoub, nice answer! +1

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var root = XElement.Load("1.xml");
        var compIDs = root.Elements()
                      .GroupBy(r => r.Element("Name").Value)
                      .Select(group => new 
                                        {
                                            Group = group.Key,
                                            Items = group.First().Elements("IDs").Elements("ID")
                                                    .Select(id => new Regex("<ID>(.*)</ID>").Match(id.ToString()).Groups[1].ToString())
                                                    .OrderBy(value => value)
                                                    .ToArray()
                                        }
                              )
                      .ToArray();

        using (var sw = new StreamWriter("results.txt"))
        {
            foreach (var group in compIDs)
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Size: " + group.Group + "\r\nIDs:");
                foreach (var id in group.Items)
                    sw.WriteLine(id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result of an ouput:

```
Size: 0005-24
IDs:
0003
0004
0005
0006
0007
0008
0009
0010
Size: 0015-24
IDs:
0003
0004
0005
0006
0007
0008
0009
0010
Size: 003-12
IDs:
0003
0004
0005
0006
0007
0008
0009
0010
```

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT: This was written before the question was amended to include XML output. It was assumed that the OP wanted to convert the data into an aggregated CLR object.*

I had this exact problem as a test in a job interview yesterday which I also struggled on, so I did a few tests of my own when I got home to make sure it was just pressure, and my brain hadn't completely fried :)

You need to group your data up, then project it into a new form in order to be able to order by the new elements. You then need to tell the GroupBy how you want to aggregate it.

You can project into an anonymous type, or a new class that you can define separately. Here I'm just using an anonymous type.

Here's a working console app. I've added some more test data to properly test the grouping and aggregation. I would suggest some additional null checking in your production app:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    internal class Program {
        private static void Main(string[] args) {
            var xml = @"<RSA>
  <Size>
    <Name>0005-24</Name>
    <IDs>
      <ID>0005</ID>
      <ID>0009</ID>
    </IDs>
  </Size>
  <Size>
    <Name>0005-24</Name>
    <IDs>
      <ID>0003</ID>
      <ID>0004</ID>
      <ID>0005</ID>
      <ID>0006</ID>
      <ID>0007</ID>
      <ID>0008</ID>
      <ID>0010</ID>
      <ID>0009</ID>
    </IDs>
  </Size>
  <Size>
    <Name>0015-24</Name>
    <IDs>
      <ID>0003</ID>
      <ID>0004</ID>
      <ID>0005</ID>
      <ID>0006</ID>
      <ID>0007</ID>
      <ID>0008</ID>
      <ID>0010</ID>
      <ID>0009</ID>
      <ID>0034</ID>
      <ID>0078</ID>
    </IDs>
  </Size>
  <Size>
    <Name>003-12</Name>
    <IDs>
      <ID>0003</ID>
      <ID>0004</ID>
      <ID>0005</ID>
      <ID>0006</ID>
      <ID>0007</ID>
      <ID>0008</ID>
      <ID>0010</ID>
      <ID>0009</ID>
    </IDs>
  </Size>
</RSA>";
            var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml));
            var reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
            var root = XElement.Load(reader);

            var names = root.Elements("Size") // Get each top level size element to make the query more efficient
                .GroupBy(r => r.Element("Name").Value, // Group by the name element
                    (key, Ids) => new {
                        Name = key,
                        Ids = Ids.SelectMany(x => x.Element("IDs").Elements("ID").Select(e => e.Value)).Distinct()
                    }) // project to new form and evaluate the group
                .OrderBy(x => x.Name); // Order by the top level grouping

            foreach(var name in names) {
                Console.Write((string.Concat("Name: ", name.Name, " - ")));
                foreach(var id in name.Ids.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x))) {
                    // Order by the integer representation (needs additional checking with TryParse())
                    Console.Write(string.Concat(id, ", "));
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```